# Convert columns into rows backwardly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a below dataframe

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E |
| NaN | P | Q | R | S |
| NaN | X | Y | NaN | T |
| NaN | Z | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | X | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I also have a value for converting it into number of columns.
(**Note:** This value will always be different for different tables)

For this table that value is 2. (Means only 2 columns)

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | NaN |
| B P X Z X | C Q Y |
| D R | E S T |

I've tried using `df.loc` instead it gave me error.

I've seen `pd.melt` method but don't think that it satisfies my case (Haven't implemented).

**Note:** The header/columns of table will always be numbers

**Edit:** Start conversion from right to left or last column to first column

Comment: Why is first row `A` `NaN` and not `A` `B P X Z X` like the case of 3rd row consolidating columns 3 and 4 ?

Comment: @SeaBean the number of columns in first table (Input Table) is 5 if it was 6 then in first row of output table would be just like you said. Sadly, it isn't

Comment: Even of this, it is common to have the remaining column handled the last.

Comment: @SeaBean yes, if you start from last column or say from right-to-left then it's appropriate